# Weird output while summing columns using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files, a1.txt and a2.txt.

a1.txt

```
1 0.2
```

a2.txt

```
2 0.8
```

And I use the following code to sum the second column of the two files and output the result to sum.txt

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$1; b[FNR]+=$2;} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) printf "%12.6f %12.5f \n", a[i], b[i]}' a[1-10].txt > sum.txt
```

However, this returns the result:

```
2.000000      0.00000
```

The first column works as expected, but the second column's result is different from the expected 1.00000.

The correct result is obtained if I use a[1-2].txt > sum.txt

What is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why `a[1-10].txt` if you want to parse only two files with awk?

Comment: @Quasímodo, this question is a simplified version of my actual script, which deals with 48 files. It seems whenever the number 10 is involved, this issue comes up.

Comment: In shell, `a[1-10].txt` will expand to match just the files `a0.txt` and `a1.txt` (If they exist)

Comment: @Quasímodo and Shawn I see the problem now. But how to include the file a10.txt in this case?

Comment: @Quasímodo do you mind putting this as the answer? I'll accept it as the official answer. Thanks a lot!
Now, just out of curiosity. using a{1..10}.txt requires all the files a1 a2 ... a10 to be present. Is there a syntex that just sums whatever files that falls within 1 to 10?

Comment: Jacek, what do you mean with summing the files? If you mean that it detects all files that do exist and are between 1 to 10, I don't think there is a syntax that will do it directly. It can be done with a for-loop.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Well this solution is already good enough. Thanks a lot @Quasímodo

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell expands `a[1-10].txt` to `a1.txt` and `a0.txt` (if both exist). If you are in bash, you can go for `a{1..10}.txt` instead.

Concerning your awk program, your END block should not be as it is. It will work because, coincidentally, `FNR` is always equal to 1. Prefer this:

```
awk '{a=$1; b+=$2} END{printf "%12.6f %12.5f \n", a, b}' a{1..10}.txt
```

As you can see, arrays are not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. You should sum values in main block NOT in END block too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  sum[FNR]=$2
  next
}
{
  print $1,sum[FNR]+$2
}
' a1.txt a2.txt
```

Also for your answer your code has a typo in array's name

To add 2nd field of all files use:

```
awk '
{
  first=$1
  sum+=$2
}
END{
  print first,sum
}
' a{1..10}.txt
```

Comment: this code works, but similarly fails when a[1-10].txt is involved.Any suggestion on that?

Comment: As per Quasimodo's suggestion please try `a{1..10}.txt` and let us know how it goes then.